# Matrices, transposes and ranks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, and write $O(A)$ for $\{\vec x  : A \vec x = \vec 0 \}$. Prove or disprove that if $O(A) = O(A^T)$ then
$A = A^T$.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I have changed the math formatting to use set notation, among other small changes.  Please review to check that I did not unintentionally change your meaning.

Comment: The set $O(A)$ is often called the *nullspace* of $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** For example: if $A$ is invertible, then $O(A) = O(A^T) = \{0\}$.   Find an **invertible** matrix for which $A \neq A^T$.

Answer (score 1):

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$
Has only the zero solution to $Ax=0$, yet $A^T\neq A$.